# What questions were salvaged from answers?

Tags: discussion

Often new users post questions as answers instead. I've requested a way for mods to convert them to questions, instead of begging the user to do it, which they generally don't, or manually reposting them, and some people are skeptical about the idea. Let's start collecting questions that were successfully salvaged from answers to see if this feature request has potential.

Comment: Not sure how I can help here.... I don't really recall any off hand.   Most, as you said, never become questions, I think (they would often be pretty low quality questions).  If I see future ones, I could note them here.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Yes, please do! Though many are low quality, I've seen a fair number that'd be good, but it's difficult digging through the history. (Comments on deleted answers don't show up in my activity, so I can't just search for the phrases I usually use there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the **questions we've converted from answers**. If you save a question, add it here!

- [Can I use chopped white onion instead of pearl onion?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/36354/1672)

> [Original post:](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/36351/1672)
> I'm making mustard pickles and it calls for pearl onions can I use white onions chopped up?

- [Are oats gluten free?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/36623/1672) (implicitly asked, along with a comment-ish bit)

> [Original post:](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/36192/1672) Barley, rye and wheat contain gluten and they are avoided by those with Celiac disease and gluten-intolerant people. Oat was not included in this group, however, in DR OZ SHOW. I am not sure whether it is an over-sight or error. If oat is gluten free indeed, it is great.

- [Is acid required when pressure canning?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/36625/1672) (generalized from hot sauce only question)

> [Original post:](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/36614/1672) this is more of another question than answer, but is there a need for vinegar, salt or other preservatives, if I am going to pressure can the hot sauce.

- [How do I render large quantities of suet?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/39654/1672)

> [Original post:](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/39543/1672) Stephan, I am trying to render 100lb beef suet to tallow as well. Do you have an efficient way of doing this you can teach me?
>
> Did you use stove, crock pot, or stove pot? Also, how many pounds did you render each time and did you add water?

- [Can I turn coarse coarnmeal into fine with a blender?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/39655/1672)
- [Why does my rice cooker's steam hole always clog?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/39657/1672)

Comment: I'd like to see the original question too, for personal interest. Can you edit them in please? :)

Comment: @Mien I've posted a few of them here. In the future, I'll just post the original form directly, and then edit it, so that if you want to see the original question, you can look at the revision history. This is yet another reason an automated feature is a good idea - it's taking me a *lot* of work per question to document it this clearly, and that's part of why I've gotten around to saving so few of these questions.

Comment: @Mien Oops, I forgot, the five minute edit window absorbed the original version. ANOTHER good reason for the feature - it could preserve the original in revision history.

Answer (score 5):

This feature is needed, because having a moderator or other user enter the question just doesn't work well, because the owner of the question is wrong.

The person who re-enters the question won't know what a truly acceptable answer is--only the original asker can know that.  Similarly, the person transcribing the question won't be able to clarify or follow up with additional information very well.   I notices these things when I copied in some questions from the Tea and Coffee Area 51 proposal.

So even if the feature is not heavily used, I think giving mods a "convert to question" feature which properly sets the owner of the new question is a good idea.  It can then post an alert to the OP, and maybe leave leave a link in place of the original comment.

Comment: I agree about having the right owner - unfortunately you're being a little optimistic about them returning, I think. Often they won't. It's still worth getting right though for when they do though.

Comment: This would also assign rep correctly (especially if you are at the risk of downvotes)...

Comment: Yes, I totally agree - whenever possible, we should get this right. A lot of these questions are potentially good, and the OP should get the upvotes, so they can start really using the site.

Answer (score 2):

Here are **answers that may be worth converting to questions**. Note that sometimes this does take a bit of editing, and you'll need 10k rep to be able to see them, since they're already deleted. If you do convert one of these, move it to the other answer!

- [Why use baking powder instead of yeast?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/36297/1672) (very generous interpretation of the answer; has definitely been answered before, for example in [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/32294/1672), but the question isn't actually a duplicate)
- [How do I use a mandoline to julienne carrots?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/36525/1672)
- [Is there any expiry on alkaline water or kansui](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/36705/1672)
- [How do I make crepes wet, not dry and cracked?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/37442/1672)
- [How do I fix an igniter that clicks but doesn't light?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/40442/1672)
- [Can I prepare a stuffed bread but bake it on the next day?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/40507/4638)
- [How should I store powdered pistachios?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/42300/1672)
- [Mixer jumping](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/43211/1672)

A bunch more I've bookmarked (sorry, no friendly titles here, the whole reason I was bookmarking is that cleanly editing here is time-consuming). These are all from the past few months, at a rate of 1-2 per week, and mostly do not include any of the non-answers deleted by other moderators. (I stopped collecting these for most of this year, sorry.)

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/how-can-i-make-sauerkraut-to-best-preserve-the-probiotic-elements/47761#47761

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/31945/how-do-i-season-an-iron-griddle-on-an-induction-hob/47437#47437

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37649/does-simple-syrup-require-refrigeration/46126#46126

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25361/storing-bechamel-sauce/48960#48960

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22971/how-can-i-make-my-homemade-potato-wedges-crispy/47798#47798

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12861/how-do-i-convert-a-weight-of-dried-chick-peas-to-volume-of-cooked/47647#47647

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18392/can-i-re-freeze-fruit/50030#50030

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36961/why-is-milk-powder-used-in-bread-machine-recipes/47728#47728

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32007/what-does-meringue-powder-do-in-butter-cream-icing/49026#49026

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19149/how-to-customize-the-softness-of-custards-like-flan/49224#49224

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/400/what-is-the-best-flour-to-use-for-pizza-dough/49565#49565

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/31974/what-is-the-difference-between-corn-flour-and-corn-meal/49607#49607

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37001/what-are-the-differences-between-fresh-beans-and-dried-ones/49308#49308

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/what-does-vanilla-extract-add-to-a-recipe/49264#49264

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/53579/1672